# Advice on using .NET 3.0 syntax and compiling for 2.0 please

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Will a DLL built using the 3.0 compiler but targeted at the 2.0 framework definitely run on machines with only the 2.0 runtime?

*Details:*
To date we've been building using the .NET 2.0 compiler in order to ensure compatibility with the 2.0 runtime.  Now we'd like to included some third-party source that contains 3.0 syntax, but we still need to be compatible with the 2.0 runtime.  We're therefore considering changing to the 3.0 compiler for our production builds, but targeting the 2.0 framework.

While it seems like this should work, it is a little scary, so we'd really like to hear from someone who's tried this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following C# 3 features while still targeting the 2.0 runtime:

- Automatically implemented properties
- Object/collection initializers
- Implicitly typed local variables/arrays
- Anonymous types
- Lambda expressions

You may use the following C# 3 features with 2.0 runtime with a [hack](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Using-Extension-Methods-In-Fx-20-Projects.aspx):

- Extension methods

You may not use the following:

- LINQ extensions
- query syntax

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it will work, because the compiler extensions are just syntactic sugar. Just make sure it's using the correct service pack.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the third party library doesn't reference libraries not in the target runtime, you are fine. C# 3.0 compiles to IL code just as C# 2.0 and all syntactic additions are confined to the C# language only.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. .NET 3.5 and the output of the C# 3.0 compiler is binary compatible with the .NET 2.0 compiler.